What should I do about the electrical outlet that sits right on the edge of where my kitchen backsplash will end?
I am adding a tile backsplash to my kitchen, between the counter and the overhead cabinets (about 18" height).
There is a poorly located electrical outlet in the line where my backsplash would end. Should I:

slice off a half inch of outlet cover plate (least effort)
relocate the entire outlet into (or out of) the backsplash area (most effort)
something else entirely



Stop the backsplash tile 1/2 inch (or whatever the dimension is) short , so it ends at the edge of the outlet cover.

How about option #4 - tile around the outlet, cutting tiles, and leaving the electrics alone?

I'm going to assume that that outlet is sitting on one side of a stud... move it to the other side or move it <=== that way on to the next stud. Now you have it not on the edge. (Exact movement would depend on if you want to move it off of the counter top ==> that way - to not interrupt the counter top - or if you want to move it <== that way to be part of the counter top "experience".)

@WernerCD Electrical code may constrain how far to the left you may move that outlet. Chances are that it is in that odd position because it cannot be further left than it is without violating code.

The answer depends where the cable(s) comes in, and which side of the outlet the stud is on.

@Dúthomhas that begs the question and standard "I am not an electrician" and "talk to your local lawyer" responses on local code and the like - which I hope is obvious. What's code in Utah isn't code in Jersey and what's normal in US isn't normal in Mexico.

@WernerCD What is obvious to you is not obvious to everyone, making it worth mentioning.

What kind of outlet box and plaster ring is that outlet mounted in? If it's a 4×4 box with a centered opening, you might be able to replace the ring with one that has the opening to one side.

I would use the opportunity to turn this socket into 4 sockets (or whatever number allowed in your code) because I) there are never enough sockets and ii) when they are enough they are not in the right place (this is a fact that derives directly from the Heisenberg uncertainty principle in physics. Trust me, I have a PhD)

@Dúthomhas if you can't move it left, move it right.  Of course it could be too close to the sink to go left, and too close to a stud to easily go right - and depending on your wiring, moving it could be an issue.  Where I am, cables buried in walls have to run vertically or horizontally from electrical boxes, so if the room is wired on drops from above, you couldn't really go through the stud.

@Bladeski has a good idea but it would be better if we had a less zoomed-in photo (not a common comment here).  In a similar place in my kitchen we carried on the tiles to the door recess that was close to the end of the worktop

The first step is to determine whether you need the receptacle or not (almost certainly "yes") and, if so, where it needs to be.
Generally speaking (there are some exceptions) you need (a) a receptacle at least once every 4 feet and (b) each place on the counter should be within 2 feet of a receptacle. You also don't have to make things comply with current code (but I'll note one really good idea below) but you can't make things worse.
In your case, that likely means:

You probably can't get rid of the receptacle because it is quite likely that there are places on the existing countertop that are closer to this receptacle than to any other receptacle and are more than 2 feet away from any other receptacle.
Assuming the above is true, you really shouldn't move this farther away - i.e., away from the backsplash - because that would make things a little bit worse by making some part of the countertop more than 2' away that is currently exactly 2' away.

You really don't want to chop the faceplate. Trivial to do. But (a) possibly not safe (because that may leave an exposed opening to the junction box) and (b) it will look really strange, which goes against the idea of making things look better with a nice backsplash.
Which leaves: Move the receptacle into the backsplash area. How? That depends on what is inside the wall. If there is currently a stud to the left of the receptacle then move the receptacle to the other side of the stud. If there is currently a stud to the right of the receptacle then it is harder to say what the best location is.
There are going to be three key challenges:

Cutting through the backsplash. That can get a bit tricky with tile. It will probably make sense to pick the exact position partly based on minimizing the number of tile cuts needed. But basically, figure out the desired position, move/install the junction box and then measure carefully and cut the tiles before installing them on the wall. The good news is that the faceplate (and there are some larger sizes available) can hide rough tile cuts.
Tile depth. If the receptacle were already in the backsplash area (you may have some other receptacles that are in that situation) then you would add a box extender to handle the extra depth. But since you are moving the box, you can simply install it such that the front of the box is in front of the drywall so that it is flush with the tile once installed.
Cable or conduit. If your receptacle is currently connected to non-metallic cable (a.k.a., Romex) then if it is coming from the left you won't have any issues. If it is coming from the top or the right then you will need an extra few inches. The simple solution to that problem, if it occurs, is to move the receptacle up if the cable is coming from above or down if the cable is coming from below, in order to get a few extra inches to move the box. What you can't do is to splice the cable in the wall. If you have conduit then this gets potentially quite a bit more complicated.

GFCI - A really good idea!
Your receptacle may be protected by a GFCI breaker or by another receptacle that has GFCI protection built-in. If so, fine. If not, then this is the time to replace it with a GFCI/receptacle. GFCI protection is extremely important in kitchens and has been required for decades. You probably don't have to add it now if you don't already have it, but it is a very good idea to do so and costs very little for potentially life-saving protection.

I would be really surprised if the outlet spacing along the wall above the counter is such that it's exactly 2' max distance to any country appliance.

Excluding any anomalies due to going around corners it's trivial to get outlets spaced 4 feet apart to within builder tolerances.  Wall studs are normally installed with 16" center to center spacing, so all that needs to be done is to install a box on every 3rd stud.

Follow electrical code anyway
You should follow electrical code whether or not you are technically required to do so. Electrical code exists to protect you and your house from stupid stuff happening.
Don’t move the outlet
Moving the outlet left is likely to move it too close to whatever your water source is.
Moving it at all is a whole lot of pain: you’d have to replace drywall and repaint, not to mention mess with the electrical in ways that are not fun.
(You should, however, swap that outlet out for a GFCI, though, assuming that there is no protection elsewhere on the line.)
Don’t cut the outlet cover
I know that people do this, and often enough it works fine. Just remember, that cover exists to protect you (and kids!) from the wiring behind the cover.
If you do chop the cover, you need to make sure that the backsplash performs the same function. This means that the old cover and the backsplash must join in a way in that, say, knives or pennies or fingers or whatnot cannot be inserted between the chopped cover and the backsplash.
What makes it worse, though, is that doing this makes any future maintenance on that outlet a nightmare, because access to the box is now restricted by installed backspash tile on one side and by drywall and plastic (or metal!) on the other.
DO trim the backsplash around the outlet.
People do this all the time. It looks fine. It works great. And it does not make life difficult for future maintenance.
Here is my (very quick, very poor) edited version of what that may look like using a simple metal image from the internet:

It would obviously be much prettier if you used tile. Either way, it looks fine and is infinitely more maintainable and, importantly, no more difficult to install than it would otherwise have been. Win!

I'm not clear on how this works if the tile has a thickness.

@Mark You have to cut the tile around the outlet (as in my picture). You have to cut the tile to install it anyway, so this is not an issue. Tile should not be more than a quarter inch thick, so it is not an issue wrt the outlet cover, but even if it is you can buy box “extenders” for that.

Something that could drastically improve this look is changing the color of the outlet to more closely match the back splash.  In this example a sliver outlet and cover, and perhaps changing the paint a bit will make this more pleasing to the eye.

How about an offset mud ring. Looks like it should offset the outlet far enough out of the backsplash so you can use a standard plate on it. This will require some patching but it looks like your wall could use some patching. This assumes you have a double gang box in the wall.  If it were me and if it wasn't a major project I would move the outlet further into the backsplash for aesthetic reasons.

A potential solution would be to purchase a slim fit outlet cover.
There a several ranges that do outlets that are the same width as the inner part of the outlet show, without the outer part.
Some basic DIY would be required to make good the hole left behind, but one side would be covered by the splashback.



slice off a half inch of outlet cover plate (least effort)


It will probably look okay-ish once you learn to ignore it.


relocate the entire outlet into (or out of) the backsplash area (most effort)


Yes, this would be preferential. Make it a double-gang while you're at it.
Let's hope this is the final outlet on the circuit so that you can freely move the wire.


something else entirely


Stop the backsplash early?

If you think that doing things "right" is time-consuming and expensive then you'll be happy to hear that doing them wrong is twice as expensive because you won't be satisfied with the result and will likely have to do it again.

I've heard the last paragraph phrased "if you don't have time to do it right, when will you have time to fix it?"

@PeteBecker To which the former owner of my house would gleefully reply "Bold of you to assume I'm not selling it right after doing everything wrong."

Both.  Add a double outlet over the counter for counter things and one at standard wall height for room things eg vacuum.
If you're doing a backsplash the extra cost and effort for this is trivial.

I would look at moving the outlet from the wall to the side of the kitchen cabinet.  If the cables come up from the floor inside a stud wall and local regulations allow it would be easy without needing to change cables.
Moving a socket if the cable needs expending is always hard as the connector needs to go somewhat and always best if such connectors are easy to access in a visible location.
